# How to revert to the original datafarme from a joint probablity dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

If I have a dataframe and computed the joint probability table for it. Can I use that joint probability table to generate the original dataframe ? I looked at similar [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73681614/python-using-calculated-joint-probability-distributions-on-existing-data-to-cre?rq=2) but it was asking to generate a new random data. I want to generate the original data with the original number of rows.

Here is my code for generating the joint probability table:

```
    def compute_joint_probability(input_csv):
        """
        Compute the joint probability for each row in the input CSV file and add it as a new column in the output CSV file.
    
        Args:
            input_csv (str): Path to the input CSV file.
            output_csv (str): Path to the output CSV file.
    
        Returns:
            None
        """
        output_csv = 'JointProb.csv'
        df = pd.read_csv(input_csv)
        N=len(df)
        # Fill NaN values with a placeholder to include them in the count
        df_filled = df.fillna('NaN')
        
        # Count the occurrences of each unique row, including rows with NaN
        row_counts = df_filled.groupby(df_filled.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index(name='P')
        row_counts[row_counts.columns[-1]]= row_counts[row_counts.columns[-1]].apply(lambda x: x / N)
        # Save the counts to a new CSV file
        row_counts.to_csv(output_csv, index=False)
```

and here is my code to revert to the original data :

```
import random
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import csv

def revert(joint_prob_csv, original_data_csv):
    # output_csv = 'JointProb_'+input_csv
       # output_csv = 'revert.csv'
        #output_csv = 'data_processing/JointProb.csv'

        # Read the joint probability CSV
        joint_prob_df = pd.read_csv(joint_prob_csv)

        # Calculate the total row count from the last column in the joint probability CSV
        N = int(joint_prob_df.iloc[:, -1].sum())

        # Remove the probability column to get the original data
        original_data_df = joint_prob_df.iloc[:, :-1]

        # Create a list to store the original rows
        original_rows = []

        # Iterate over the rows of the joint probability data
        for _, row in joint_prob_csv.iterrows():
            # Repeat each row according to its probability
            repeat_count = int(row['P'] * N)
            original_rows.extend([row[:-1]] * repeat_count)

        # Convert the list of original rows to a DataFrame
        original_data_final_df = pd.DataFrame(original_rows, columns=original_data_df.columns[:-1])

        # Save the original data with the actual row count to a new CSV file
        original_data_final_df.to_csv(original_data_csv, index=False)

        return original_data_csv


# main 
revert( 'JointProb.csv', 'revert.csv')
```

It does not generate the correct output. Note that I want to keep the NaN rows even if they are present in the joint probability table
Is there a way to retrieve the original dataframe with the actual row counts given the joint Probability table as input ?

Comment: why not use the original data which is faster and easier ?

Comment: sometimes I only have access to the joint probability table

Comment: fair enough.  please provide the forward calculation so that we know what we are reversing exactly...